# Having two Organization schema in one site is bad?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

Is it bad to have two `Organization` schema? It's basically an old version created by Yoast, and an updated version in JSON-LD.

I would like to retain the old one so that my whole site is still running Yoast SEO, and at the same running JSON-LD mark up codes.

If it's bad, then is there a way how to get rid of it?

Comment: 1) I’m not familiar with Yoast -- what does it use? Microdata? RDFa? 2) Does "old version" mean that the data coming from Yoast is not up to date? Or do both `Organization` items have the same data? 3) Are you able to edit/change both `Organization` items?

Answer (score 1):

Json-LD is indeed considered to be the "newest" protocol which is what i believe you are referring to as "new" and "old".  This is a nice description of different types :

> I'll cover Microdata and RDFa in same because they're similar. So they
>   both are addition to HTML attributes indicating what Schema.org field
>   names correspond with what user-visible text on the page. Works
>   perfect but need lot of developer work and designer changes. Because
>   both backend (admin interface) and frontend (HTML) must be changed.
>   And there are many issues that can be messed - incorrect
>   implementation, "rich snippet spam", software bugs, etc. Look easy as
>   1-2-3 but in reality it's pain (PIA) for implementation and support.
>   Example - only product implementation require in backend least 10 edit
>   boxes if they're manual filled.
>
> JSON-LD - it's relative new protocol based on Schema.org. The main
>   benefit is that you split representation layer (HTML) from semantic
>   layer (JSON-LD). In prev. formats - they're same and linked each
>   other. Now they're split. This give you much more freedom than before.
>   You can place HTML data whatever you wish and just add hidden JSON in
>   head or in content that will add semantic marking. This is future (for
>   now).

My personal preference is JSON-LD,  reduced html bloat, ability to insert data without disrupting the flow of site is a must,  its also the preferred protocol by Google which was confirmed by John Mueller back in 2016.

To answer your question though,  if you wish to remove a certain part of the markup from your site, simply remove your values from Yoasts plugin and rely on your own JSON-LD alone.

For example the following screenshots should contain NO data if you do not want to implement Yoasts markup.

[image]
[image]

If you also have Yoasts breadcrumbs on your site,  you can disable those ( if you do not need the user experience side of visual breadcrumbs ) and you could use a plugin like this :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-ld-breadcrumbs/

To enable JSON-LD breadcrumb markup, without the visual bloat.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not creates any issue. But google will preferred inline html tags over json-ld.

If other schema on your site were inline html tags, then the case is that it would not going to read your json-ld.

The preference always getting to inline tags over the others way. The reason behind this is very simple. Sometimes user hide the content from user and show only for search engine. So google avoid json-ld in most cases. But sometimes, it worked with the websites for whom the inline schema implementation is not easier, they goes for json-ld only.

So, it's up to you which one you made more comfortably.

Comment: Couldn't be further from the truth,  Google's John Mueller outlined a year ago that json-ld has started to become Google's preference over inline schema.

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering structured data markup using json-ld format and schema.org vocabulary + Yoast SEO? If yes, then both are totally different.

Schema markup is used to describe things on your page and it explains google what it "means". Schema markup doesn't help you to rank high in Google SERP; but it might help you to increase CTR. This markup you can provide either via JSON LD format, Microdata or RDFa.

For example if you apply a Product markup then Google understands which products are listed on your page, how much is minimum and maximum price, how much is the stock, user ratings etc. Imagine if one has 4.8 star rating our of 5 and has  competitive price on Google SERP, then his link is more clicked than his competitors. Theoretically it reduces your bounce rate and increases CTR.

On the contrary, Yoast SEO is used for the meta details on the page which helps you for ranking. It helps you to add on page meta details like page title, description, keyword, alt text, and helps to optimize your content.